# How do I make the following function called "animal_delete_func()" put the deleted animal entry into the deleted_animals table?

Tags: mysql

Here is the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION animal_delete_func()
RETURNS TRIGGER
BEGIN 
  -- Delete the feeding schedule entries for the animal

  DELETE FROM feeding_schedule WHERE animal_id = OLD.animal_id;
  
  -- Delete the food entries for the animal

  DELETE FROM food WHERE animal_id = OLD.animal_id;
 
 -- INSERT into deleted_animals table

    INSERT INTO deleted_animals (animal_id, animal_name, date_deleted)
    VALUES (OLD.animal_id, (SELECT animal_name FROM animals WHERE animal_id = OLD.animal_id), NOW());
 
 RETURN OLD


END$$

-- Set delimiter back to ;
DELIMITER ;

-- trigger that calls animal_delete_func() everytime an animal is deleted from the animals table

CREATE TRIGGER animal_delete_trigger
AFTER DELETE ON animals
FOR EACH ROW
CALL animal_delete_func();
```

I was expecting that the function would put the deleted animal entry into the deleted animals table, but it doesn't work.

Comment: This may not be what you are looking for, but why not just add a "deleted" boolean to the animals that is set to true once they are deleted. Then you can still differentiate current and deleted animals and you don't have to worry about moving them between tables.

Comment: You shouldn't need to delete from the other tables explicitly. Declare the foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: You don't need the subquery in the `INSERT`, just use `OLD.animal_name`

Comment: `RETURNS TRIGGER` is not valid in MySQL. I think that's only in PostGreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have `RETURN TRIGGER` like PostGres does. Use an ordinary stored procedure, and pass the animal ID as a parameter.

The `SELECT` subquery that gets the animal name can't work, since the trigger runs *after* that row has been deleted. So pass `OLD.animal_name` as a parameter.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE animal_delete_func(old_animal_id, old_animal_name)
BEGIN 
    -- Delete the feeding schedule entries for the animal

    DELETE FROM feeding_schedule WHERE animal_id = old_animal_id;

    -- Delete the food entries for the animal

    DELETE FROM food WHERE animal_id = old_animal_id;

    -- INSERT into deleted_animals table

    INSERT INTO deleted_animals (animal_id, animal_name, date_deleted)
    VALUES (old_animal_id, old_animal_name, NOW());
 
 RETURN OLD


END$$

-- Set delimiter back to ;
DELIMITER ;

-- trigger that calls animal_delete_func() everytime an animal is deleted from the animals table

CREATE TRIGGER animal_delete_trigger
AFTER DELETE ON animals
FOR EACH ROW
CALL animal_delete_func(OLD.animal_id, OLD.animal_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a stored procedure syntax instead of a trigger syntax:
Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER animal_delete_trigger
BEFORE DELETE ON animals
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- Delete the feeding schedule entries for the animal
  DELETE FROM feeding_schedule WHERE animal_id = OLD.animal_id;
  
  -- Delete the food entries for the animal
  DELETE FROM food WHERE animal_id = OLD.animal_id;
  
  -- INSERT into deleted_animals table
  INSERT INTO deleted_animals (animal_id, animal_name, date_deleted)
  VALUES (OLD.animal_id, OLD.animal_name, NOW());
  
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```